# WIndows 7 MAK deactivation

Tags: windows-7, windows, licensing, deactivation

I have 50 MAK Windows 7 licensees.  I want to reformat my computer for a fresh install.  How do I do this without needing to activate a 2nd time?  The computer is still functioning and in fact I used it for this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reactivate the MAK key you used on that PC once you format/reinstall Windows.

> Yes. MAKs allow a predetermined number of activations. This number depends on the type of agreement you have. The number of activations can be revised (at the request of the customer or of Microsoft) to accommodate your regular usage.
>
> You can find the number of activations remaining on a MAK by going to the [VLSC](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/home.aspx), or by using the Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT). If the existing activation limit on your MAK is inadequate for your deployment, contact the Microsoft Activation Center.

from [Microsoft's Product Activation FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation-faq.aspx).  In other words, each MAK key you have may be activated more than once. Microsoft keeps track of these at VLSC and realizes you might need to format a PC.

tl;dr Just format, install windows and activate using the same MAK key as before, you'll be fine (atleast for a couple of times).

Comment: If you run out of activations due to reinstalls, at least with retail keys, then use the phone activation system. when it fails it will redirect you to a live operator, explain the situation to that person and they will 'rearm' the key for additional activations.

Answer (score 0):

Use ABR, http://directedge.us/content/abr-activation-backup-and-restore